# want to remove error message in custom login form in django custom login

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i don't want user have to see this message without any error i load page this come automatically here is my views.py

```
def my_login(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('accounts:home')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('<h1>Page was found</h1>')
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html", {'form': form})
```

my forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User does not exist.")
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User is no longer active.")
            return super(LoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

[image: the screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to submit your form only when you receive a POST request.

```
def my_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # process form here
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    # send form to template
```

You will find more info about this in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#the-view).